# Entering text into texbox after label

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I have an auto generated class id for a class "FormFieldContainer". I want to enter text into the **Text Box_13** (also auto generated ID).
The only consistent value in this scheme is a preceding label **"Broker Code"**. How can I enter text into the text box by using the label as a reference?

HTML below. Apologies for the formatting. I'm still struggling with this :-(

```
<div class="FormFieldContainer" id="my_test_FormFieldContainer_15" widgetid="my_test_FormFieldContainer_15">
<link href="/tswApp/my/test/FormFieldContainer.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<div data-dojo-attach-point="formFieldHeaderPoint" class="FormFieldHeader">
   <div data-dojo-attach-point="formFieldContainerLabelPt" class="FieldLabel">Broker Code</div>
   <div data-dojo-attach-point="requiredIndicator" class="FieldRequiredIndicator" style="display: table-cell;">(required)</div>
   <div data-dojo-attach-point="formFieldLinkContainerPoint" class="FieldLinkContainer"></div>
</div>
<div data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode" class="Field">
   <div data-dojo-attach-point="inputContainer" class="SimpleInputContainer">
      <div role="presentation" id="widget_dijit_form_TextBox_13" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft dijitTextBox" widgetid="dijit_form_TextBox_13">
         <div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer"><input type="text" autocomplete="off" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" tabindex="0" id="dijit_form_TextBox_13" value=""><span class="dijitPlaceHolder dijitInputField" style="">Enter broker code</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="ClearButton widgetHidden"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
//div[text()='Broker Code']/../..//input
```

If that's the only input control I suggest you to use tagname with `input`

Comment: Thanks Saifur. This worked and I will accept it as the answer. Thanks to alecxe as well.

Answer (score 3):

Or, alternatively, you can rely on the "Enter broker code" text, which is in the `span` tag right after the desired `input` element. [`preceding-sibling` axis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/preceding-sibling) would help:

```
//span[. = 'Enter broker code']/preceding-sibling::input
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about using the "Enter broker code" but I am not 100% sure it will remain static. I am certain though the preceding **Broker Code** label will.